# DB-First Entity Framework context not showing my tables

Tags: entity-framework, db-first

This is my first time dealing with Entity Framework. I add the ADO.NET Entity Data Model class -> Choose the database to use -> Choose the tables I want -> Name / Namespace -> Finish

When I look at the class in the solution explorer, there's no tables showing.
When I instantiate it, it doesn't show my tables as options.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Choosing tables

[image]

Empty Diagram once finished loading

[image]

Breakdown of class

[image]

Comment: You have an error or warning and the diagram / context doesn't get created.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
Here is the solution.
In my case, there were some warnings about the primary key. That primary keys are not defined in tables so. What I did I define the primary keys and then update the table. Now I have the diagrams.